# How to avoid Selenium being detected when answering captcha?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a Python script which login on a page ([sso.acesso.gov.br](https://sso.acesso.gov.br/login)) using some credentials and them usually answer a captcha using 2Captcha API.

The problem is that recently it takes an error after captcha answer, even when I answer it manually.
By the way, the error message received is different than when I forced answer wrong, which makes me believe that my script has now being detected somehow by the website.

If I open a Chrome browser as a user and just do the same steps, I can login, sometimes even without captcha. And all times without an error.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from fp.fp import FreeProxy

user_path = 'C:\\PythonProjects\\User Data'
driver_path = 'C:\\PythonProjects\\107\\chromedriver.exe'


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

## Tactics to avoid being detected as automation
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')

## User profile
options.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir={user_path}")

## User agent
ua = UserAgent()
options.add_argument(f'--user-agent={ua.random}')

## Proxy
proxy = FreeProxy().get()
options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server={proxy}')

## Set browser
driver = uc.Chrome(
    driver_executable_path = driver_path,
    options = options
)

## Set device memory info
driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'deviceMemory', {get: () => 8});")

## Set navigator webdriver to undefined
driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined});")

## Open page
driver.get('https://sso.acesso.gov.br/login')

## From this point I insert CPF (user) and password, then answer captcha using 2Captcha
## I also have tried just set the browser and navigate manually, inserting data and answering captcha, but no success
```

Do you have any suggestion to bypass this block?
I have no idea about what is detecting and blocking my browser.

If I use my script on [bot.sannysoft.com](https://bot.sannysoft.com/), I get the following results:

[Intoli tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yRdk.png)

[Fingerprint Scanner 1/2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnF6G.png)

[Fingerprint Scanner 2/2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LHOG.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver

Answer (score 0):

Add couple of seconds wait before you enter correct captcha first time, that might work unless its designed otherwise.